# What is the function of the ft2build.h in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

My ubuntu is 12.10.
When I read some others code, I found the head file ft2build.h.
I found it in the usr/include/.
Who can tell me the function of it? Or when we will need to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try opening the file, it says right at the top:

> Build macros of the FreeType 2 library.

Comment: Yes, but it just contain:#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>. Why do not we just use the ftheader.h instead of ft2build.h?

Comment: @shining: Yep! That's the actual header file. If you read the notes, you'll notice it's a generated header file.